# Need help in JSON parsing

Tags: json, swift

I am getting data from API and I need to filter the array of dictionary based upon "total_price" tag, now the condition is I want only those flights whose price is between "35.0" to "55.0"

```
{
    airline = 9W;
    "available_seats" = "<null>";
    bags = (
    );
    currency = USD;
    destination = 38551;
    origin = 39232;
    "price_details" = {
    };
    "rate_plan_code" = WIP;
    routes = (
    );
    taxes = "17.51";
    "total_price" = "31.7";
}
```

As the total_price tag is coming as string I am not sure how to filter it using predicate etc. I need to filter the json response itself, no models were created for this API response.

Comment: I suggest you create models then using `Codable` to decode your json. After that it should be pretty easy to filter on a price interval

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I agreed with your solution, but its an old app. and i have to change a huge logic to make it done, Just looking for any approach to filter it directly from the json?

Comment: Take a look at Swift JSONSerialization then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to filter on prices I assume you get an array and I have further assumed in my code this array is inside a dictionary with the key "flights" so you need to change this key to whatever you have

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
        if let flights = json["flights"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            let filtered = flights.filter {
                if let str = $0["total_price"] as? String, let price = Double(str) {
                    return price >= 35.0 && price <= 55.0
                }
                return false
            }
            print(filtered.count) // replace with more meaningful code :)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Decode failed: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Joakim Thanks a lot , You are a genius :) it works like i needed.